# Can Microsoft OneNote be executed on Ubuntu?

Tags: laptop, sync, microsoft, smartphone, stickynotes

I don't have an Ubuntu machine available now and this question is not very much on a problem to solve but is kind of a follow up to [a question I have asked on Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/72357/a-simple-notes-application-shared-between-a-laptop-and-a-smartphone) by which I try to find the best (laptop-smartphone synchronized) sticky notes app for others and myself (by the standards given there).

### My problem

I would like to know if [Microsoft OneNote](https://products.office.com/en/onenote/digital-note-taking-app?rtc=1) be executed on Ubuntu but I don't have an Ubuntu machine available now.

### My question

Can Microsoft OneNote be executed on Ubuntu (and if so, have you used it to synchronize sticky notes on your laptop's desktop node with your smartphone --- if you use one)?

Comment: The is a "OneNote Desktop Client for Linux" in standard Ubuntu repositories, which you can install using the Ubuntu **Software** installation GUI (i.e., `gnome-software`). I haven't used it; so I cannot comment on its features.

Comment: I tried it out, because of the fact, that I use OneNote regularly.... @FedonKadifeli 
So I give a short summary: The package is simply onenote.com in an app. With other means: It works, but it didn't convince me. If you want to know if this fits to you, just try to use onenote.com (for example) for a week in your browser and then you know if it fits to you...(In my experience it's slow)